# Any way to use 6in4(Protocol 41) through nat?

Tags: internet, ipv6, ip-address, tunnel

Any way to use 6in4(Protocol 41) through NAT as my ISP wont give public IP's.

If not, any other IPv6 Tunnelbrokers that can pass through NAT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are behind a Carrier grade NAT and without a static IP, most likely
you cannot use 6in4.

6in4 doesn't have the typical IPv4 TCP/UDP headers, so most
NAT implementations don't get enough information to determine a flow
to pinhole permit the traffic.
As such, 6in4 tunnels almost never work through a CGNAT environment.
There's no initial handshake with a 6in4 tunnel, each end just sends the
IPv6 traffic at the other side with an IPv4 IP header added on top.

You would need for that a
[Teredo tunneling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teredo_tunneling)
server and client on both ends, if you are in Windows.
Linux has implemented the similar
[Miredo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miredo).

Comment: About Miredo, I get miredo: error while loading shared libraries: libtun6.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

But thanks for the help